# python function to return a tuple of filenames without extensions and dictionary where file extensions are keys and file names are values

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write a function in python, which will get a filename as a parameter. The file contains filenames with and without extensions. The function will make a dictionary with extensions as keys and list of filenames with that particular extension as values. At the end, function will return a tuple where first part of that tuple is a list of filenames without extensions and the other part is dictionary described above. The code I have written is pasted below:

---

```
import re
def file_extensions(filename):
    with open(filenames, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.read()
        ext = re.findall(r'\w+\.?\w+\.{1}(\w+)', lines)
        f.seek(0)
        lines_dict = f.readlines()
        d = {k:[v] for k, v in zip(ext, lines_dict)}
    return ([filenames without extensionts], d)
```

---

The contents of the input file are:

---

```
file1.txt
mydocument.pdf
file2.txt
archive.tar.gz
test
```

---

The function should return:

---

```
(["test"], { "txt" : ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"], "pdf" : ["mydocument.pdf"], "gz" : ["archive.tar.gz"] } )
```

---

However, my function is not complete, I am first struggling with the dictionary and then to make the list of file names without extensions.

---

EDIT:
I have been able to write the function now,below is my code:

---

```
def file_extensions(filename):
    with_ext = []
    ext = []
    no_ext = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            res = line.rstrip().rsplit('.',maxsplit=1)
            if len(res) == 1:
                no_ext.append(res[0])
            else:
                fulna = '.'.join(res)
                ext.append(res[1])
                with_ext.append(fulna)
        dicta = {k:[v] for k, v in zip(ext, with_ext)}
    return (no_ext, dicta)
print(file_extensions('filenames.txt'))
```

---

It prints:

---

```
(['test'], {'txt': ['file2.txt'], 'pdf': ['mydocument.pdf'], 'gz': ['archive.tar.gz']})
```

---

There is one thing it does not do. Which is, in the dictionary, it should append all the filenames with the same extension as values infront of the extension. Comparing below the original output vs expected output:

---

```
Original output of my code:
(['test'], {'txt': ['file2.txt'], 'pdf': ['mydocument.pdf'], 'gz': ['archive.tar.gz']})

Expected output:
(["test"], { "txt" : ["file1.txt", "file2.txt"], "pdf" : ["mydocument.pdf"], "gz" : ["archive.tar.gz"] } )
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regex for this, you could just iterate and split the filename with [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) and append to the dict or list according to the size of the result.

```
>>> with_ext = defaultdict(list)
>>> no_ext = []
>>> with open('example.txt', 'r') as f:
...     for line in f:
...             res = line.rstrip().rsplit('.',maxsplit=1)
...             if len(res) == 1:
...                     no_ext.append(res[0])
...             else:
...                     with_ext[res[1]].append(res[0])
... 
>>> no_ext
['test']
>>> with_ext
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'txt': ['file1', 'file2'], 'pdf': ['mydocument'], 'gz': ['archive.tar']})
```